# regex - check if pattern exists inside a string

Tags: python, regex

" This string has some errors such as EXCEPTION mod Name - this is the exception"

I want to extract module name which is always located between EXCEPTION and space - space

How can I do this ?

I was thinking re.match() will be the closest way of doing this?

Rather I need a way to check if a pattern exists. Like re.search() and return a boolean.
I want to basically grep for "EXCEPTION.* - "

Please note: I need to search for two things in the same line --> word EXCEPTION and a dash " - "
The module name is always after the word EXCEPTION and before the " - "

```
1  90890612:23:15,895 EXCEPTION SomeClusterScheduler:70 - Lost executor
2 21/02/02 11:54:22 EXCEPTION Executor: Exit as unable to send beats
```

Comment: `if 'EXCEPTION ' in s

Comment: actually I need to check for not just EXCEPTION --- I need to check for "EXCEPTION" which is followed by dash ' - '

Comment: In the example you gave EXCEPTION is followed by Module Name not dash '-'

Comment: Yes I meant -- I need a way that searches for both the word exception and dash 
Not just exception. 
The module name will be in between the word EXCEPTION and DASH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses regex.
Try this if it works:

```
import re
s = "90890612:23:15,895 EXCEPTION YarnClusterScheduler:70 - Lost"
x = re.search(r"EXCEPTION\s(.*)\s-", s)
if(x):
    print(x.group(1))
else:
    print("No Module")
```

**Output**

```
YarnClusterScheduler:70
```

Comment: No actually I want to use the split ONLY if this sort of pattern exists.
So first I want to search if this pattern exists in the line. Since my file has many lines, I do not want to split on every line.

Comment: I need a way to first check if a pattern such as EXCEPTION followed by a dash ' - ' exists in the line. And only then I want to split after.

Comment: Is module name just after EXCEPTION??

Comment: YES, the module name is after EXCEPTION and before the dash '-' --> so I need to make sure both exists while searching

Comment: Just one quick question --> so the dash has one space before it and one space after it. Is there a way to incorporate that as well?

Comment: \s represents one space in string, so you can use r"EXCEPTION\s(.*)\s-\s" it will work the same

Comment: Also, Like you saw on the line two, its possible that the EXCEPTION does not have a module. So I want to skip those lines that do not have module and don't want to run this on each line. So instead, first I want to check if this pattern exists and only then find the module.

Comment: This regular expression will filter that and line 2 will be rejected

Comment: I mean, if I run this on lines that don't match the pattern, it will keep failing. So is there a way I can grep for "ERROR.* - " to first check that this pattern exists ? and only then extract the group.

Comment: did you want the module name or the module name + the line number ?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to approach this, one of which is the following:

```
mystring =  "1  90890612:23:15,895 EXCEPTION YarnClusterScheduler:70 - Lost "
keyword = 'EXCEPTION'
before_keyword, keyword, after_keyword = mystring.partition(keyword)
print(before_keyword)
print(keyword)
print(after_keyword)
```

**Output**

```
1  90890612:23:15,895 
EXCEPTION
YarnClusterScheduler:70 - Lost
```

This way, you partition your string in 3 three parts. One before the keyword (which is useless for you), the keyword itself and one after the keyword (which is the part you want). If you dont need the whole string after your keyword, you can split that according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
import re


s = "1  90890612:23:15,895 EXCEPTION YarnClusterScheduler:70 - Lost"

match = re.match(r".* EXCEPTION (.*):[0-9]+ - .*", s)
module = match.group(1) if match else ""

print(module)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 so.py
YarnClusterScheduler
```